# Go back to previous ViewController not working for multiple view controllers in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

How to return back to previous view controller programmatically? I found this answer, but there is an example that demonstrate how to go back if we have navigation stack:

`self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`

It's ok in case my queue of controllers based on navigation controller. 
There are multiple viewControllers all connected with navigationView Controller when I am going to next view controller and tabbing back are working fine but from next to next , I am tabbing back and stuck in a loop means I am stuck between 2nd and 3rd view controller not going to first view controller.

Comment: you need to use this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621886-popviewcontroller

Comment: can you please tell me how can i use this??

Comment: the popViewController method works by taking you back to one VC from the stack of all viewControllers maintained by navigation controller. Lets say: you have 3 VC in app A,B,C. A goes to B which goes to C. Now you need to call self.navigationcontroller.popviewcontrolleranimated(animated: true) to go back one VC. From C, you will goto B and from B, back to A.

Comment: Kindly share your code to let other understand what problem are you facing.

Comment: @praveensrivastava - It's not quite clear from your question... Are you using a `UINavigationController` or not?

Answer (score 2):

Try this :-
//For moving to previous screen

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

//For moving to your root view controller ! This will clear your //navigation stack.

```
 self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

//To move to a specific view controller eg:- TargetVC

```
for obj in (self.navigationController?.viewControllers)! {
        if obj is TargetVC {
 self.navigationController?.popToViewController(obj, animated: true)
            break
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In a `navigation stack` **(A -> B -> C)**,

1. To move `1 controller` back **(B <- C or A <- B)**, use

   ```
   self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
   ```
2. To move to `root view controller` **(A <- C)**, use

   ```
   self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
   ```

Comment: actually currently i am using  self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) and its working fine from B to A but when come to perform c to b and then b to a sending me back to c .i don't know why.

Comment: What do you want to check? Specify it clearly please.

Comment: Dismiss works when you are presenting a controller on top of other. Pop works when you push a controller in the navigation stack. Both are different. Which one do you want to use? I think for your use case Push/Pop will work fine.

Comment: Navigation stack is only for Navigation Controller. It maintains a stack of all the controllers that are pushed.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to convey.

Comment: i am send one vc to other using present modally

Comment: That what I am saying. Push the controller instead of presenting it modally.

Comment: using pesent modelly

Comment: Presenting modally doesn't cross dissolve automatically.

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'

Comment: Embed A in navigation controller. Connect A to B using show segue. Connect B to C using show segue.

Comment: A ,B and C all are embedded to navigation Vc

Comment: bro there is only a single button which is back and on click m calling a function which is self.dismiss

Comment: Please google the difference between dismissing and popping a controller.

Answer (score 1):

Dont use dismiss. From `A to B` use `navigationcontroller.pushviewcontroller` and for `B to C` use `presentviewcontroller`.
 Then on back button of `C controller` use `dismissViewcontroller` and on back button of `B controller` use `popViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

In swift 3, try this code in button action

```
@IBAction func btnBackClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
       _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true) 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Pop PreviousViewcontroller**

```
  self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

**Pop To Root Viewcontroller**

```
  self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

**Pop To Specific Viewcontroller**

```
 let viewControllers: [UIViewController] = self.navigationController!.viewControllers ;
 for vc in viewControllers
  {
    if vc.isKind(of:YourViewController)
     {
      self.navigationController!.popToViewController(vc, animated: true)
   break;
    }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 3.0 You can use this :-

if you want to back your rootviewcontroller use This

```
        _ = self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

or if you want to go back another view controller which is added on Stack :-

```
 for obj in (self.navigationController?.viewControllers)! {
        if obj is TargetVC {
        _ =    self.navigationController?.popToViewController(obj, animated: true)
            break
        }
    }
```